# Getting Network Client MAC address, Syntax issue using PhP

Tags: php, networking, syntax, mac-address, shell-exec

Actually the below coding is working fine, if I provide the ip address directly inside the `shell_exec()`

```
$mac = shell_exec('arp -a 192.168.0.107');
```

If, I get the ip of the client from his system and stored in a variable and call the same, as given below,

```
$mac = shell_exec('arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip));
```

The output is not generating.

Here is the Full code:

```
<?php

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac = shell_exec('arp -a'. escapeshellarg($ip));

//Working fine when sample client IP is provided...
//$mac = shell_exec('arp -a 192.168.0.107'); 

$findme = "Physical";
$pos = strpos($mac, $findme);
$macp = substr($mac,($pos+42),26);

if(empty($mac))
{
    die("No mac address for $ip not found");
}

// having it
echo "mac address for $ip: $macp";

?>
```

Please advise, why `escapeshellarg($ip)` does not work in the `shell_exec()`.

Comment: Did you get your answer yet ? If not, I can help you.

Answer (score 2):

`shell_exec('arp '.$ip.' | awk \'{print $4}\'');`

---

**Result from Terminal**

└── arp 10.1.10.26 | awk '{print $4}'

**a4:5e:60:ee:29:19**

Comment: Always makes me smile when people start correctly using awk commands!

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct format:

```
$mac=shell_exec("arp -a ".$ip);
```

or

```
$mac=shell_exec("arp -a ".escapeshellarg($ip));
```

(using the `escapeshellarg` call)

Answer (score 0):

A space is missing just after the -a in 'arp -a'.escape...

So it turns into arp -a192.168.0.107

Comment: No I have removed and adding the space and tried several times, but it is not working.

Comment: update your answer accordingly because in your code, a space is missing !

Comment: have you tried to do var_dump(escapeshellarg($ip)); ?

Comment: if i use var_dump, It is listing all the ip and their mac addresses.

Comment: I meant, use var_dump(escapeshellarg($ip)) to be sure that 'arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip) == 'arp -a 192.168.0.107'

Comment: actually i alter the coding like this ** $mac = shell_exec('arp -a' . var_dump(escapeshellarg($ip)));** it will list all the IP and Mac address in my networks

Comment: use the var_dump outside the call to shell_exec.

Comment: the purpose is to verify that  'arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip) equals to 'arp -a 192.168.0.107' as you're claiming that $mac = shell_exec('arp -a 192.168.0.107'); works but $mac = shell_exec('arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip)); doesn't

Comment: $ip = var_dump(escapeshellarg($ip));
 $mac = shell_exec('arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip));
no use...
 $ip = var_dump(escapeshellarg($ip));
 $mac = shell_exec('arp -a' . $ip);
no use... till all the ip are listed

Comment: so how can i call the variable $ip inside shell_exec()?

Comment: do you know var_dump function ?

Comment: Actually i stored the client system ip address in $ip " $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];"

Comment: Actually i am new to php... i didn't know deeply.

Comment: ok var_dump is like a debug function to display the content of a variable. It's not supposed to be used like $my_var = var_dump($something). You can use it to check that 'arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip) is equals to 'arp -a 192.168.0.107' by doing on another line of code var_dump('arp -a' . escapeshellarg($ip)); to see if you're really executing 'arp -a 192.168.0.107' as you think you are

Comment: Actually my need is to get the client ip and mac address who use my php program and stored in my database with time, employee name and employee no. I will now able to store client ip using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; in DB. However I can't get the MAC address of the client system/person whom using my programs.

Comment: So the getting ip value are related to MAc address. If i give the ip address in the position "escapeshellarg($ip)". I can getting my answer... If I use "escapeshellarg($ip)" the answer is not generating. It is not possible to assign IP as $mac = shell_exec('arp -a 192.168.0.107'); since it is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me...

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac_string = shell_exec("arp -a $ip");
$mac_array = explode(" ",$mac_string);
$mac = $mac_array[3];
echo($ip." - ".$mac);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
shell_exec("arp -a ".escapeshellarg($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])." | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{1,2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{1,2}'");
```