# Is it possible to track mac address of client with PHP code. If yes how and if no why?

Tags: php, mac-address

I want to track my web app users with mac address so that I can just give access to that user to only for that device having mac address registered in my app.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php

Comment: I have already looked over it it does not have the solution @Unni Babu

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php .. those answers explain this *isn't possible* except under special circumstances (both client and server are on same ethernet segment). The MAC address is a part of the Link Layer of the OSI model - it isn't preserved beyond the local network segment as packets are handed from one router to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAC address stands for "media access control", so it is an address for a really low level in the [OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), a physical address. So, if you are running your web app in a server which is not in the same network of your users, it will be impossible, because only the public address (IP) is transmitted.

For further information regarding this, please search a bit over StackOverflow, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420381/how-can-i-get-the-mac-and-the-ip-address-of-a-connected-client-in-php).

Alternatively, and if you are in the same network, there are some other possible solutions that depend directly on your networking knowledges, such as using this [PHP library](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7048-PHP-Retrieve-the-Mac-address-of-a-network-card.html) or some [Linux scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929212/getting-network-client-mac-address-syntax-issue-using-php) (assuming that you are using Linux).